# Suppose $n^x\in\mathbb{N}$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}.$ Show that $x\in\mathbb{N}.$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, contest-math

> Let $x$ be a positive real number such that $n^x\in\mathbb{N}$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}.$ Show that $x\in\mathbb{N}.$

I saw this here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17560/if-2x-and-3x-are-integers-must-x-be-as-well. OP says that it is a "fun little puzzle", so I thought I'd try it, but haven't gotten far.

Firstly, $n^x\in\mathbb{N}\text{ }\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\iff p^x\in\mathbb{N}\text{ }\forall p\in\mathbb{P},$ where $\mathbb{P}$ is the set of all primes.

So, we might as well consider just the primes. But, now what? I think I've handled the case where $x$ is rational.

Suppose it is given that $x\in\mathbb{Q}.$ Put $x=\frac{p}{q}$ for co-prime $p,q\in\mathbb{N}.$ We wish to show $q=1.$

Now, $2^{\frac{p}{q}}=a,$ for some $a\in\mathbb{N}.$ This gives $2^p=a^q.$ This implies that $a=2^k,$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}.$ This gives $2^p=2^{kq}.$ Hence, $p=kq.$ Now, $\gcd(p,q)=1=\gcd(kq,q).$ Since $q≤\gcd(kq,q)=1,$ we get $q=1.$ Well, as soon as we get $p=kq,$ we get $\frac{p}{q}=k,$ and we are done. However, I show $q=1$ for completeness. Anyway, $x$ is a natural number. Is this right?

What do we do when $x$ is a positive irrational? Obviously in this case, we need to use all primes (or atleast $2$ primes), not just $2.$ This is because of existence of things like $2^{\log_2(3)}=3.$

PS: I don't know what tag to put for this, but number theory seems appropriate.

Comment: This is an old [Putnam problem](https://prase.cz/kalva/putnam/psoln/psol716.html)

Comment: q = 1 is not great to prove as (9)^(3/2) is also natural with (p,q) = 1

Comment: @lulu How do you find original questions so fast?

Comment: @krave For $x=\frac{3}{2},$ we don't have $2^x$ being an integer.

Comment: @Krave37, that's why I used $2,$ a prime.

Comment: Sorry, mistake on my side

Comment: @Krave37  Easy in this case:  I actually took that exam.  Didn't solve this one at the time though.

Comment: @lulu, nice! Must have been nice for you to see this 50+ years later.

Comment: Always liked this question.  Amazing to me that variants (like $2^x, 3^x, 5^x$) are so very difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Use the mean value theorem.

I wrote up a solution [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/analysis/MVT-integral-powers.pdf).